# How to deal with multiple queries in a java servlet

Tags: java, mysql

I'm trying to send an increase count variable of a picture (which is increased by just increasing +1 everytime a new session hits a picture). I'm getting the following error message however, i'm checking for an empty result set. My thought process is that I can try to select the picturesNo that has been called and if it can't find that pictureNo we simply insert the first count to the table, and if it can find it, we then update this.

Error message:
"SQLException: Illegal operation on empty result set."

Code to increase the count for the session

```
 HttpSession session = request.getSession() ;


    Integer counter = (Integer) session.getAttribute("counter");
    String accCount = (String) session.getAttribute("attributeKey") ;
    String url = "http://localhost:8080/techfore";
    String encodedURL = url + ";jsessionid=" + request.getSession().getId();

    if (accCount == null || encodedURL == null) { // New session?
        response.sendRedirect("/techfore/WelcomePage");

        }

    else{

        if(counter == 0) {

         counter = new Integer(counter.intValue() + 1);
            session.setAttribute("counter", counter);

        }
    } 



    Utilities.initalCount(out, pictureName, counter);
```

Code to run the queries

```
   public static void initalCount(PrintWriter out, String pictureName, int accessCount) {
        Connection con = null;
        try { // Connect to the database
           con = openConnection(out);
        }
        catch (Exception e) {  // Failed to open the connection
           out.println("<P>" + e.getMessage());

        }

    try {

            Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
            String query0;
            ResultSet rs1;




          query0="SELECT PictureNo FROM Statistics WHERE PictureNo = (SELECT PictureNo FROM Pictures WHERE ShortName = '"+pictureName+"')";





           rs1 = stmt.executeQuery(query0);

           if(rs1.next()){
               //yes exist
                String description = rs1.getString("Description");
               int pictureNo = rs1.getInt("PictureNo");  
               IncreaseCount(out, pictureNo, accessCount);
            }
           else {
           //if rs is null insert
           int pictureNo = rs1.getInt("PictureNo");  
           AddCount(out, pictureNo, accessCount);


           }


            stmt.close() ;




        }
        catch(SQLException ex) {
            out.println("<P>SQLException: " + ex.getMessage()) ;
         }




   }

   public static void AddCount(PrintWriter out, int pictureNo, int accessCount) {

        Connection con = null;
        try { // Connect to the database
           con = openConnection(out);
        }
        catch (Exception e) {  // Failed to open the connection
           out.println("<P>" + e.getMessage());
           return;
        }



        try {

            Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
            String query;
            ResultSet rs1;





            query="INSERT INTO Statistics VALUES "+pictureNo+","+accessCount+" ";


            stmt.executeUpdate(query);


            stmt.close() ;






        }
        catch(SQLException ex) {
            out.println("<P>SQLException: " + ex.getMessage()) ;
         }

 }

   public static void IncreaseCount(PrintWriter out, int pictureNo, int accessCount) {

        Connection con = null;
        try { // Connect to the database
           con = openConnection(out);
        }
        catch (Exception e) {  // Failed to open the connection
           out.println("<P>" + e.getMessage());
           return;
        }



        try {

            Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
            String query;
            ResultSet rs1;





            query="UPDATE Statistics SET AccessCount = "+accessCount+" + 1 WHERE PictureNo = "+pictureNo+"";


            stmt.executeUpdate(query);


            stmt.close() ;





        }
        catch(SQLException ex) {
            out.println("<P>SQLException: " + ex.getMessage()) ;
         }

  }
```

New insert

```
 query="INSERT INTO Statistics VALUES (SELECT PictureNo FROM Pictures WHERE FileName = '"+pictureName+"'),"+accessCount+" ";
```

Comment: You're calling rs1.getIn() even though rs1.next() returned false. There is no row in the resultset, so you can't get anything from it.

Comment: I'm getting a new error now i've fixed that and changed my statement slightly. My insert statement is now calling the line i've added at the bottom. But it's saying there is a syntax error.

Comment: `query="INSERT INTO Statistics VALUES (SELECT PictureNo FROM Pictures WHERE FileName = '"+pictureName+"'),"+accessCount+" ";` should be `query="INSERT INTO Statistics VALUES (SELECT PictureNo,"+accessCount+" FROM Pictures WHERE FileName = '"+pictureName+"') ";` Anyway, you should take a look at [PreparedStatements](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html)

Comment: My problem is, that the access count cannot be stored in the pictures table. So is there anyway to keep the accessCount seperate from the subquery?